# include C declarations with void argument list in C++ program creates compilation error (using gcc version 6.3.0 20170406)

Tags: c++

I have always used:

```
extern "C"{
    #include <editline.h>
}
```

and the editline.h file contains the two following lines:

```
extern char *readline();
extern void add_history();
```

In the c++ code I use:

```
char* mbs=readline((char*)"> ");
```

and the compiler issues: error: too many arguments to function 'char* readline()'

I understand that in C leaving the argument list empty in the declaration of a function means : "some fixed arguments but undefined".

The code worked in the past, so something should have changed, maybe in the editline.h file or between g++ versions.
What is the correct behaviour regarding the g++ compiler ?

Comment: `(char*)"> "` Danger Will Robinson! What's going on here?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. `extern "C"` does not magically make the C++ a C compiler. Don't use the C for C++ questions.

Answer (score 4):

Wrapping declarations in `extern "C"` doesn't transform them into C code. It just affects name mangling, allowing for linking between the two languages.

The feature you're using doesn't exist in C++, so you can't use it here. C++ simply sees no matching function.

Instead of wrapping entire `#include` statements in `extern "C"` and hoping for the best, a C header should be *designed* to be compatible with C++ callers; such code will typically have `extern "C"` at appropriate locations in the header itself, and will avoid C-only features like this.

In short, unless you can "fix" the header, you're out of luck.

Comment: Does it means that headers valid for C aren't useable without modification in C++ ?

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: No, it means that headers invalid for C++ aren't usable without modification in C++.

Comment: Also I don't understand how this worked in the past, unless you enstrictened your C++ compiler flags, or a language extension was removed/disabled in GCC.

Comment: The code was previously #include <editline/readline.h> so something has changed there.

Comment: Your question says the code worked in the past. Now you claim it's different code. Which one do I believe?

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis Read carefully the section of this answer that begins "instead of wrapping". That's how you make headers that work in both C and C++. There's no magic way to make *every* C header work in C++ without possibly requiring changes. The two languages are too different and almost anything can appear in a header file.